# Portable like installer with Wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to create an installer with Wix allowing by default to install the application in program files for users having admin right. 
In that case, the `InstallScope="perMachine"`

In the same installer; I want allow the user having to admin rights to install the application on his profile with `InstallScope="perUser"`

How can I add a choice between these 2 options in the installer?